# antlr4 - any text and keywords

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to parse the following:

```
SELECT name-of-key[random text]
```

This is part of a larger grammar which I am trying to construct. I left it our for clarity.

I came up with the following rules:

```
select      : 'select' NAME '[' anything ']'
            ;
anything    : (ANYTHING | NAME)+
            ;

NAME        : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | '-' | '_')+
            ;
ANYTHING    : (~(']' | '['))+
            ;
WHITESPACE  : ('\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n')+ -> skip
            ;
```

This doesn't seem to work. For example, input `SELECT a[hello world!]` gives the following error:

```
line 1:0 mismatched input 'SELECT a' expecting 'SELECT'
```

This goes wrong because the input `SELECT a` is recognized by `ANYTHING`, instead of `select`. How do I fix that? I feel that I am missing some concept(s) here, but it is difficult to get started.

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe the concept you are missing is rule priority.

[1] Lexer rules **matching the longest possible string** have priority.

As you mentioned, the ANYTHING token rule above matches "select a", which is longer than what the (implicit) token rule 'select' matches, hence its precedence. Non-greedy behaviour is indicated by a question mark.

```
ANYTHING    : (~(']' | '['))+?
```

Just making the ANYTHING rule non-greedy doesn't completely solve your problem though, because after properly matching 'select', the lexer will produce an ANYTHING token for the space, because ...

[2] Lexer rules **appearing first** have priority.

Switching lexer rules WHITE_SPACE and ANYTHING fixes this. The grammar below should parse your example.

```
select      : 'select' NAME '[' anything ']'
            ;
anything    : (ANYTHING | NAME)+
            ;

NAME        : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | '-' | '_')+
            ;
WHITESPACE  : ('\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n')+ -> skip
            ;
ANYTHING    : (~(']' | '['))+?
            ;
```

I personally avoid implicit token rules, especially if your grammar is complex, precisely because of token rule priority. I would thus write this.

```
SELECT      : 'select' ;
L_BRACKET   : '[';
R_BRACKET   : ']';

NAME        : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | '-' | '_')+ ;
WHITESPACE  : ('\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n')+ -> skip ;
ANY         : . ;

select      : SELECT NAME L_BRACKET anything R_BRACKET ;
anything    : (~R_BRACKET)+ ;
```

Also note that the space in "hello world" will be swallowed by the WHITESPACE rule. To properly manage this, you need ANTLR *island grammars*.

'Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! I learned a lot here. I was indeed not really thinking about priority of rules. I changed my grammer, and it is working fine now. I made a lot of improvement here. Thank you!

Comment: By the way. I tried to upvote your answer, but I don't have enough reputation points yet. I will do it later once I have them.